# When sending integer through PrintWriter from server to client, no parsing is possible

Tags: java, server, client

I am programming a little server-client-programm, which sends a text from one client who is writing on a file, to the other clients with the same filename, and got the following error
[image]

But I am just sending an integer and no other characters...

Here's the code:

Server

```
String[] splitter = scanText.split("\n");
String length = splitter.length + "";

//sending scanText to clients
for (PrintWriter pw2 : userMap.get(filename) ) {
     if(!pw2.equals(pw))
     {
        pw2.println(length + "\n" + scanText); 
     }
}
```

Client

class "UpdateInBackground" is a class which is in the Client-class

```
class UpdateInBackground extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int lines; //to know how much lines are send from the server
        String scanText;
        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
            scanText = "";
            lines = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); //here I get the error
            while (lines-- > 0) {
                scanText += sc.nextLine() + "\n";
            }
            output.setText(scanText);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@asparagus, please define sc in line sc.nextLine(), considering this is an object from class Scanner, I need to know the input. The question must be self explainable with the definitions of variables and what are the inputs.

In Class UpdateInBackground, 
lines = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());// here nextLine() is for any String , please refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())

Reason for NumberFormatException : You are converting the value to int, without knowing, what is getting as input.

Try to use exception handling, to know what types of errors, might just come, to avoid the program getting struck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
But why is it that characters, which obviously cannot be shown in the ouput, are in front of the number of lines (1)?

Comment: May I know your input(sc.nextLine()), or set of inputs, so I can help you with the solution.

Comment: to check the unwanted character, being added, just print on console as follows: System.out.println(sc.nextLine().length), before parsing it to Integer.